# VBA for Conditional Formatting to Format Multiple Rows with Different Values?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to create a VBA formula that would apply conditional formatting using information in one cell, and apply it to a different cell? For example:

[image]

In the picture above, I have a value in "Change (Points). There is also a value in "Standard Deviation (Points)". I want to be able to use conditional formatting so that it highlights red when the value of column "Change (Points)" is below the value of column "Standard Deviation (Points)". I also want to be able to use conditional formatting so that it highlights green when the volume of column "Change (Points)" is above the value of column "Standard Deviation (Points)".

I also need to do this for 200+ rows, and each value in column "Standard Deviation (Points)" is different. Is there anyway to create a VBA formula so that I would not have to do this manually for each row?

I don't know how to really use VBA, so I haven't tried much of anything.

Comment: Doesnt conditional formatting allow you to specify a range of cells? just change the range

Comment: You can use Conditional formatting with formula-based rules for this.  https://exceljet.net/conditional-formatting-with-formulas

Comment: Yes, thank you. I realized that there is a button that allows you to drag it down to the different cells.